# Splitting a string into consecutive counts?

Tags: python, string, list-comprehension

For example, if the given string is this:

```
"aaabbbbccdaeeee"
```

I want to say something like:

```
3 a, 4 b, 2 c, 1 d, 1 a, 4 e
```

It is easy enough to do in Python with a brute force loop, but I am wondering if there is a more Pythonic / cleaner one-liner type of approach.

My brute force:

```
while source!="":
    leading = source[0]
    c=0
    while source!="" and source[0]==leading:
        c+=1
        source=source[1:]
    print(c, leading)
```

Comment: What is the brute force loop you come up with? Mind if you edit the question to include that there?

Comment: @metatoaster I'm not sure how it's relevant, but I added my method to the OP.

Comment: It is to show you that attempted this and we can also use that to build upon your solution to something better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for a count of each distinct letter in the string regardless of position:

```
>>> s="aaabbbbccdaeeee"
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(s)
Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 4, 'e': 4, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

You can use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) if the position in the string has meaning:

```
from itertools import groupby
li=[]
for k, l in groupby(s):
    li.append((k, len(list(l))))

print li
```

Prints:

```
[('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('a', 1), ('e', 4)]
```

Which can be reduce to a list comprehension:

```
[(k,len(list(l))) for k, l in groupby(s)]
```

You can even use a regex:

```
>>> [(m.group(0)[0], len(m.group(0))) for m in re.finditer(r'((\w)\2*)', s)] 
[('a', 3), ('b', 4), ('c', 2), ('d', 1), ('a', 1), ('e', 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to solve the problem. @dawg has already posted the best solution, but if for some reason you aren't allowed to use `Counter()` (maybe a job interview or school assignment) then you can actually solve the problem in a few ways.

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def counter_counts(s):
    """ Preferred method using Counter()


    Arguments:
        s {string} -- [string to have each character counted]

    Returns:
        [dict] -- [dictionary of counts of each char]
    """

    return Counter(s)

def default_counts(s):
    """ Alternative solution using defaultdict


    Arguments:
        s {string} -- [string to have each character counted]

    Returns:
        [dict] -- [dictionary of counts of each char]
    """

    counts = defaultdict(int)  # each key is initalized to 0
    for char in s:
        counts[char] += 1  # increment the count of each character by 1

    return counts

def vanilla_counts_1(s):
    """ Alternative solution using a vanilla dicitonary


    Arguments:
        s {string} -- [string to have each character counted]

    Returns:
        [dict] -- [dictionary of counts of each char]
    """

    counts = {}
    for char in s:
        # we have to manually check that each value is in the dictionary before attempting to increment it
        if char in counts:
            counts[char] += 1
        else:
            counts[char] = 1

    return counts

def vanilla_counts_2(s):
    """ Alternative solution using a vanilla dicitonary
    This version uses the .get() method to increment instead of checking if a key already exists


    Arguments:
        s {string} -- [string to have each character counted]

    Returns:
        [dict] -- [dictionary of counts of each char]
    """

    counts = {}
    for char in s:
         # the second argument in .get() is the default value if we dont find the key
        counts[char] = counts.get(char, 0) + 1 

    return counts
```

And just for fun lets take a look at how each method performs.

For `s = "aaabbbbccdaeeee"` and 10,000 runs:

```
Counter: 0.0330204963684082s
defaultdict: 0.01565241813659668s
vanilla 1: 0.01562952995300293s
vanilla 2: 0.015581130981445312s
```

(actually rather surprising results)

Now let's test what happens if we set our string to the entire plaintext version of the book of Genesis and 1,000 runs:

```
Counter: 8.500739336013794s
defaultdict: 14.721554040908813s
vanilla 1: 18.089043855667114s
vanilla 2: 27.01840090751648s
```

Looks like the overhead of creating the `Counter()` object becomes much less important!

(These weren't very scientific tests, but it was a bit of fun).